# WSO2 Identity Server - Get Role's Permissions

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

refer to this [link](https://github.com/nilasini/CustomPermissionClaimHandler) we integrated `CustomPermissionClaimHandler` to our server without any errors but still we can't get the permissions of the users... I know how to create custom claims refer to this [link](https://medium.com/@inthiraj1994/lets-add-a-custom-claim-to-oidc-in-wso2-is-d871e418d6b0) and if I follow these 2 links' steps, I can create permission field like a textbox as shown on picture (`testClaim` and `organizationID` are examples about that from picture)... I thought that after integrating  `CustomPermissionClaimHandler` I would see permissions like Role field as shown on picture with blue line but still it comes with empty textbox as shown on picture with green line. Is there any way to get the permissions?

[image]

EDIT: I can get JWT including my custom claims and if I decode it I see like this (as you see it doesn't contain permissions):
[image]

Comment: When you use `CustomPermissionClaimHandler`, you can't see the values under the user profile's permission attribute, but the permission list will be returned in the idToken. Don't you get the permission list in the idToken?

Comment: What is the version of IS you use?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna I can't see the permissions on idToken too... We use 5.10.0

Comment: I added the JWT accessToken response, nearly same as idToken

Comment: Since you used a customClaimHandler, it will only change the claims handling with Idtoken or jwt access token. That will not persist in the user store. Only the claims that get from userstore, will be shown under the user profile. So by using customClaimHandler, you can't view claims from user profile.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the JWT response, I can say you have done either or both of the following.

1. It seems there is a mistake in the guide of configuring the application-authentication extension.

If you have added,

```
[authentication.framework.extensions]
claim_handler="com.wso2.sample.claim.handler.CustomClaimHandler"
```

in to the deployment.toml, but you use the jar by building the code, there is a mismatch in the package name. You have to use the following config.

```
[authentication.framework.extensions]
claim_handler="org.wso2.custom.claim.PermissionClaimHandler"
```

Because of this configuration issue, your custom handler may not get executed even though that service got activated properly.

2. If the claim handler is active and the configuration is correct as step one,  you might have missed something when mapping the custom claim to an oidc claim / adding it as an OIDC sope / configuring service provider claims

Comment: we see that claim handler is active because we see a log, most probably we have problem on mapping but we follow all steps, I'm adding local claim with 'claim uri = http://wso2.org/claims/permission' and 'display name = permission' and 'description = permission' and 'mapped attr = permission'. After I add external claim so 'dialect uri=http://wso2.org/oidc/claim' and 'external claim uri = permission' and 'mapped local claim = http://wso2.org/claims/permission'. After, at Manage -> OIDC Scopes -> openid -> Add claims, I add the 'permission'.

Comment: After, I go to my SP and I add the claim on Claim Configuration

Comment: What I missing? Do you have idea ?

Comment: Still we see permission field with empty textbox on user profile

Comment: permission field of the user profile will not be field any time since we do not store the permission values on the user store. But this handler is responsible for returning the permission in the id token/ jwt access token.

Comment: understand, but still we can't get the permissions on JWT

Comment: actually I don't care about permission field on user profile. I just want to get the permissions on JWT

Comment: What is the userstore type that you use? Is it an LDAP/JDBC userstore? Do you see any errors on the carbon logs when the user login to the application? or do you see the log `INFO {org.wso2.custom.claim.PermissionClaimHandler} - Get permission list for the user <username>` when a user logs into the SP?

Comment: JDBC. And we dont see your log. We see '[2021-02-25 08:53:46,057] [] INFO {org.wso2.custom.claim.internal.PermissionClaimHandlingComponent} - Carbon Custom Claim Handler activated successfully.'

Comment: The log that you mentioned is printed when activating the bundle. Even though the bundle is activated, if you haven't added the correct package as my 1st option in the answer this couldn't be achieved. Can you add the deployment.toml config under `[authentication.framework.extensions]`? Also, we need to check whether that config is populated into the `<Extensions>` tag in `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/application-authentication.xml` file

Comment: we putted on deployment.toml and we see <ClaimHandler>org.wso2.custom.claim.PermissionClaimHandler</ClaimHandler> into the <Extensions>

Comment: have you tried to return another claim in the access token? (for eg: testClaim on your setup). If that works properly and you have configured the same steps for permission claim we can suspect the issue is with claimhandler configs

Comment: yes, I tried, also if I fill the empty textbox of permission field like "abc", I can see ' "permission":"abc" ' on acces token and id token

Comment: Since you don't see https://github.com/nilasini/CustomPermissionClaimHandler/blob/760afb87c987b512ea710c822e4c4f5bd06b5f42/src/main/java/org/wso2/custom/claim/PermissionClaimHandler.java#L45 log printed in carbon logs when a user loginto the application, it seems your claim handler is not working

Comment: According to the first comment of this thread, your local claim URI is "wso2.org/claims/permission". Isn't it given as `http://wso2.org/claims/permission`?